# Segment.io NPM Package not working with Meteor

Tags: meteor, npm, segment-io

I am using the npm package for segment server side with Meteor

In my packages.json folder I have

```
"segmentio": "0.1.4"


if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.startup ->
    @analytics = Meteor.npmRequire('segmentio')
    analytics.init(Meteor.settings.segmentio)

    analytics.track
      event: 'hello'
      userId: '2'
```

That the code I am using to track an event with segment server side. But the event is not showing up in the debugger. Any advice? What am I doing wrong?

I know I am using the correct `Meteor.settings.segmentio` key because I am using the same key on the client and those events are tracked just fine. But on the server, the 'hello' event I posted above will not track. No errors are thrown when the code above runs.

Comment: If no errors are being thrown, I'd double check the value of `Meteor.settings.segmentio`. Maybe it's not getting read properly or you copied the wrong value.

Comment: I am using `Meteor.settings.segmentio` on the client with analytics.js and it is working. So I know the key is right. All the client side calls are coming through. The code above is what I am using for server side. No errors are thrown. But I do not see the event in the debugger.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the code setup slightly wrong.

Scoping issue. Here is the working code:

```
@analytics = null

if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.startup ->
    analytics = Meteor.npmRequire('segmentio')
    analytics.init(Meteor.settings.segmentio)

    analytics.track
      event: 'hello'
      userId: '2'
```